# Display a form in a console application at a particular point(in the middle of execution)

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to display a form in the middle of a console application to display some status information and automatically close the form when a particular event occurs. Will the following code portion will be enough for this purpose?

**Display the form**

```
ModuleInitializerForm moduleInitializerDlg = new ModuleInitializerForm()
{
  Parent = parent,
  TopMost = true,
  TopLevel = true,
  Text = Common.MESSAGE_INFO_TITLE,
  ControlBox = false,
  FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
  KeyPreview = false,
};

moduleInitializerDlg.Initialize();
moduleInitializerDlg.ShowDialog();
```

**Close the form**

```
public void OnModuleInitializationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
      this.BeginInvoke(new ECEventsHandler(OnModuleInitializationCompleted), sender, e);
    }
    else
    {
      this.Close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you running the form on its own thread?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @Maanu: (expanding Lasse comment) the problem using ShowDialog is that the execution of the thread is blocked until the form is closed. Hence, if you have just one thread, that form will never be closed by an event triggered in the same thread...

Comment: @digEmAll: The ShowDialog will be invoked from one thread and OnModuleInitializationCompleted will be invoked by a threadpool thread

Comment: Using `.ShowDialog()` you will never proceed to the unsubmitted code that starts the background task and binds the event handler on the form.

Comment: Have you *tried* the code that you've posted?  If so... is it not working in some specific way?

Comment: @Jodrell In managed code there is no true "console app". Instead a "console app" can write to the console and also show Winforms/WPF windows (if it wants to and has referenced the correct assemblies). The difference is if you select "Console application" as output is that a console is always shown, i.e. it is opened if the app is not started from the console.

Comment: @Daniel Rose, thanks for clarifying my hazy point and muddled understanding. +1, original comment deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using ShowDialog(), the thread where this is done will be blocked until the user (or you) close the form.

Note that if you used Show() instead, the thread will continue. However, if you have no-one pumping windows messages on that thread, the form will be "dead", i.e. it won't respond to anything. If you start with a normal console app project, then this will be the case. If you use ShowDialog(), it creates a local message loop so the window responds.

So you will need have a separate thread for the Windows Forms UI where you show the form. I would use `Application.Run(moduleInitializerDlg);` instead of ShowDialog(), since it better sets up/tears down the message pumping architecture as far as I can tell. That call will block the thread in the same way as ShowDialog() by the way.

Comment: Could start your work thread before calling `Application.Run()` but make sure the handler still works if the form has not been shown yet.

Answer (score 0):

go to the properties of the form wich should open on click...
go to the Layout section and put Start position to Centerscreen or if u have a parent in wich u want to dock it each time, use CenterParent...

enjoy!