# Run a windows form while my console application still running

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I'm new at C# programming and i'm lost with a thing that could be simple.

Executing a console application, at a moment i need to call a Windows Form that will show statics of the execution but when i call the form1.ShowDialog(); this stop the console runtime.

How do i keep my console execution alive while i show a Windows form screen ?

```
 class Program
{
    static Form1 form = new Form1();
    public static bool run = true;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        work();
    }

    public static void work()
    {
        form.Show();
        while (run)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Console still running");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Display a form in a console application at a particular point(in the middle of execution)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804792/display-a-form-in-a-console-application-at-a-particular-pointin-the-middle-of-e)

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804792/display-a-form-in-a-console-application-at-a-particular-pointin-the-middle-of-e

Comment: when i use form1.Show(); the execution continues but the form don't finish the load: puu.sh/kR4Rn.png

Comment: can you post the code where you use `Form1.Show()`?

Comment: http://puu.sh/kR5e8.png

Comment: wait I'll try and reproduce the problem if possible

Comment: I think you should try to Thread it

Comment: why are you using the while statement? is it really needed?

Comment: No i just need to check if the console still running while my form is showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this it work on me

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

class Program
{

    public static bool run = true;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Startthread();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    private static void Startthread()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {

            while (run)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("console is running...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });

        thread.Start();
    }
  }
 }
```

Threading is like "process inside a process" in my own understanding.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804792/display-a-form-in-a-console-application-at-a-particular-pointin-the-middle-of-e). You have to use `Form1.Show()` because `Form1.ShowDialog()` pauses execution until the form is closed.

**Update** This seems to be working (with Application.Run):-

```
public static Form1 form = new Form1();
    public static bool run = true;
    [MTAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(() => Application.Run(form)).Start();
        new Thread(work).Start();
    }

    public static void work()
    {

        while (run)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Console Running");
        }

    }
```

Comment: when i use form1.Show(); the execution continues but the form don't finish the load: http://puu.sh/kR4Rn.png